# Download a file using XHR in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, data-uri

I am trying to add the functionality to download a file hosted in a server. To access the file I have to send the `Authorization` header, thus I have to send an XHR request to get the file from the server. Since the file content is in a variable, I have to create a data url to make it available as the `href` attribute of an anchor tag and click it programmatically to download the file.
It's working good in almost all the browser (Except IE11, for which I have written a separate code), but in iOS Safari (in some versions of iOS), it's giving errors. Here's the code that I am using -

```
var isBrowserIE = window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob;
var dataHref = 'https://example.com/doc.pdf';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', dataHref, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
xhr.responseType = isBrowserIE ? 'blob' : 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        //For IE11
        if (isBrowserIE) {
            // Create a new Blob object using the response data of the onload object
            var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });

            var bool = window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, docName);
            if (!bool) {
                alert("Download failed, Please try again later");
            }
        } else {
            var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
            var i = uInt8Array.length;
            var binaryString = new Array(i);
            while (i--) {
                binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
            }
            var data = binaryString.join('');

            var base64 = window.btoa(data);

            var dataUrl = 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,' + base64;
            var element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', dataUrl);
            element.setAttribute('download', 'doc.pdf');
            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            element.click();
            document.body.removeChild(element);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Download failed, Please try again later");
        closeWindow();
    }
};

xhr.send();
```

Here's the possible error I am getting which is related -

`Safari cannot open the page.<br><br>The error was: “Data URL decoding&nbsp;failed”.`

Is there anything I missed which is the reason for this error? The error is occuring only in iPad 4 and iPad 5, but working in iPad mini and iPhone XR. Not sure why is it working in some versions of iOS devices and not in others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I finally figured it out. Here's my final code with explanations in comments (Sorry for ES5 code, I needed to support IE11 and the current project is not using babel yet) -

```
/* exported DownloadHandler */
/* global Uint8Array*/
var DownloadHandler = (function() {
  function isMobileDevice() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i);
  }
  function isChromeBrowser() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Crios|Chrome/i);
  }
  function isIEBrowser() {
    return window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob;
  }
  function isSafariBrowser() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Safari/i);
  }
  function getResponseType() {
    // Both Desktop Chrome and IE supports blob properly
    // Chrome also supports Data URI way, but it fails miserably when the file size is more than 2 MB (Not sure about the exact limit though).
    if (isIEBrowser() || isChromeBrowser()) {
      return 'blob';
    } else if (isMobileDevice()) {
      return 'arraybuffer';
    }
    return 'blob';
  }
  function getBlobUriFromResponse(response) {
    var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  function getDataUriFromResponse(response) {
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(response);
    var i = uInt8Array.length;
    var binaryString = new Array(i);
    while (i--) {
      binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
    }
    var data = binaryString.join('');

    var base64 = window.btoa(data);

    var dataUrl = 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,' + base64;
    return dataUrl;
  }
  function downloadFileUsingXHR(fileName, fileUrl, fileMimeType, requestType, headersList) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(requestType, fileUrl, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', fileMimeType);
    for (var i = 0; i < headersList.length; i++) {
      var header = headersList[i];
      xhr.setRequestHeader(header.key, header.value);
    }
    xhr.responseType = getResponseType();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        //For IE11
        //IE uses blob with vendor specific code
        if (isIEBrowser()) {
          // Create a new Blob object using the response data of the onload object
          var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: fileMimeType });

          var bool = window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
          if (!bool) {
            alert('Download failed, Please try again later');
          }
        } else {
          var dataUrl;
          if (this.responseType === 'blob') {
            dataUrl = getBlobUriFromResponse(this.response);
          } else {
            dataUrl = getDataUriFromResponse(this.response);
          }
          var element = document.createElement('a');
          // Safari doesn't work well with blank targets
          if (!isSafariBrowser()) {
            element.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
          }
          element.setAttribute('href', dataUrl);
          element.setAttribute('download', fileName);
          element.style.display = 'none';
          document.body.appendChild(element);
          element.click();
          document.body.removeChild(element);
        }
      } else {
        alert('Download failed, Please try again later');
      }
    };

    xhr.send();
  }
  return {
    downloadFileUsingXHR: downloadFileUsingXHR
  };
})();
```

Here's how to use the above code:

```
DownloadHandler.downloadFileUsingXHR('example.pdf', 'https://example.com/doc.pdf', 'application/pdf','GET',[{key:'Authorization',value:'Bearer ' + token}]);
```

I'll probably convert it into a library later and post a link here. I'll get the chance to refine the code too