# jQuery - Ajax load() not working on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    var id = 800;
    $("#username").load("getuser.php?p="+id);
    }, 5000);
</script>

<html>
<div>
<span class="account-content" id="username"></span>
</div>
</html>
```

This function is working on Mac Safari, the value is able to load into the span but it doesn't work on iPhone Safari. I inspected the network on iPhone, and the `getuser.php` API is returning correct value every 5seconds but the value doesn't show in the span.

Comment: Why on earth would you name a script file (or route) on your server `getuser.php800`

Comment: Think your url is incorrect, You should add "/" like `$("#username").load("getuser.php/"+id)`

Comment: @CBroe it's a typo here, it should be .php?p=800 , edited

Comment: @RaviMakwana its my typo here, its edited on the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download a file using XHR in iOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825077/download-a-file-using-xhr-in-ios-safari)

Answer (score -1):

Try to start from a document validation. The script tag outside of html is a completely invalid code.

https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: its just a part from the entire script